# How to create an index route using Flask Blueprint

Tags: python, flask

Trying to organize my project, I can't access an index page, for example, when I access `localhost:5000/`, it's calling the `posts/index`. I would like to call `/templates/index`, but I'm not finding a example.

Example structure:

```
|--__init__.py    
/views
     |--posts.py
     |--users.py
    /templates
     |_/posts
       |--index.html
       |--add.html
     |_/users
       |--index.html
       |--add.html
     |--index.html
```

The init file, I'm importing the blueprint

```
from website.views import posts
from website.views import users
app.register_blueprint(posts.mod)
app.register_blueprint(users.mod)
```

The views file, calling the routes. This example is the `posts.py`.

```
mod = Blueprint('posts',__name__)

@mod.route('/')
def index():
 return render_template('posts/index.html')

@mod.route('/add')
def add():
 return render_template('posts/add.html')

@mod.route('/edit')
def edit():
 return render_template('posts/edit.html')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a prefix during the blueprint registration.

```py
from website.views import posts

app.register_blueprint(posts.mod, url_prefix='/posts')

# /
@app.route('/')
def index():
 return render_template('index.html')
```

```
mod = Blueprint('posts',__name__)

# posts/
@mod.route('/')
def index():
 return render_template('posts/index.html')

# posts/add
@mod.route('/add')
def add():
 return render_template('posts/add.html')

# posts/edit
@mod.route('/edit')
def edit():
 return render_template('posts/edit.html')
```

source: http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/blueprints/#registering-blueprints

Answer (score 0):

Flask by default will look into the `templates` directory when it needs to render a page (html).

In your case, you specified `posts/index.html` which means it will be translated to `templates/posts/index.html`. You need to simply indicate that you want to render just the `index.html` and that will automatically reference the `templates/index.html`.

You can do this for instance using

```
@mod.route('/')
def index():
 return render_template('index.html')
```

You can however find more details at [Rendering Templates](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/quickstart/)

Comment: My init file must contain @app.route('/')... or this route should be in some views files?

Comment: You can maintain it where it currently is, in the views file where you have it now.